# Cannot call cellForRowAtIndexPath in didSelectRowAtIndexPath without affecting Animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have checked all duplicate questions. But i didn't find solution for this one. If my question is not proper, please correct me.

I have custom cell with label(For Title) and textview(For Description). I am trying expandable cell. First it will display only title and when i hit, it will display description. Hence at starting textview(Description) will be hidden(which i'll specify in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) I will make it visible whenever user touches the cell which i'll detect in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function and i'll change the height too.

i know i can use `[tableView reload]` function to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But i am using

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for Animation when height changes. Here, if i use `[tableView reload]` , Animation not working. The data displays perfectly but without animation.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
  [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I want `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to be called inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` without affecting the animation.

Thanks for the time (:

My Code :

```
#import "MyListViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface MyListViewController ()
@property NSArray* tableData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *expandedIndexPath;
@end

@implementation MyListViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.secondary.text = @"adfasdfasdfsdfsdffassssssddalfdsaldjsfadsfasdfdjsfldsjfakldsfjlasfaksfjadksfaldfjladksfjadksfjdkslsdjjlkflasfaljfajfalkflkadslsdfljksdfajsdasdfjlkafsjlkasdjfafsdjadfjksadjsladfjsajladfjslas";
    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        cell.primaryLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.secondary.hidden = NO;

    }else{
        cell.primaryLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.secondary.hidden = YES;
    }
       // cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"creme_brelee.jpg"];
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //[tableView reloadData];
    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {

        return 100.0; // Expanded height

    }
    return 30.0; // Normal height
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
  [tableView endUpdates];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;

    self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
 }




@end
```

Comment: Have you try to reload particular row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];//indexpath of your selected row
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I can't understand how this works... when i used `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` instead of `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` , it sets animation for both title and description. But i don't know how `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` works perfectly. It simply sets animation for description alone even though it reloads whole row. Can you explain this ?

Comment: The purpose of UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic is to let the table view automatically select an animation that looks good.

For example, when a row is being inserted at the beginning of a section, the table view will use UITableViewRowAnimationBottom. When it's is being inserted at the end of a section, the table view will use UITableViewRowAnimationTop.

Comment: Here you are not adding any new row so that UITableViewRowAnimationBottom is not proper.

Comment: It creates another problem. It affects only current row but i want the previously expanded rows to be closed. Hence i need to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not just current row.

Comment: That you have not mentioned in question " I want to close previously expanded rows".

Comment: You have created sections inside tableview?

Comment: No sections.. only cells.. Wait i'll post the full code.

Comment: You have to manage your previous indexpath also which you want to collapse.

Comment: How can i achieve it ? Can you update your answer with my code please ?

Comment: Actually I can not write whole code. you can write logic by yourself.

Comment: Hey...  No problem..   I did it and got output as I expected..   Thanks btw

Comment: if possible, can u suggest me any good tutorial or website to learn clearly about UITABLEVIEW except developer. apple?  It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: They gave tuts mostly by using storyboards...  not programmatically.....

Answer (score 1):

you should this and change animation as per your requirement

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.expandedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: the animation applies for both title and description. I want to set animation only for description (tableView)